# Texlive fonts screwing up my truetype fonts

Tags: fonts, latex

I have been running into this strange issue.

When I install texlive fonts, they automatically register as system fonts.
If I install the texlive variant of an already installed truetype font (for example Dejavu) it gets overridden by the texlive font and looks horrible.

I'm using OpenSuSe 12.3 and 13.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fonts are registered in `etc/fonts`.

```
usr@host:/etc/fonts# grep tex . -r 
./conf.avail/65-fonts-texgyre.conf: <dir>/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre</dir>
./conf.avail/65-fonts-texgyre.conf: <dir>/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math</dir>
./conf.avail/65-fonts-lmodern.conf: <dir>/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm</dir>
./conf.avail/65-fonts-lmodern.conf: <dir>/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm-math</dir>
```

Just remove the concerning defs and rerun `fc-cache`.